# Mobile-responsiveness, works on the web, doesn't work on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I have a website, **[girlsjustwannahavefont.com](http://girlsjustwannahavefont.com/)**

The website is almost done, but the functionality is questionable on mobile devices. When I click on the 'view my process' button on mobile devices, it doesn't work? But it works fine on the web. Can any HTML, CSS, JavaScript god shed some light as to why that's happening?
**To clarify, the button doesn't work on Safari or when it was tested on my iPhone.**

This is the CSS code for the modal.

```
.modal {
  background-color: $yellow;
  z-index: 300;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px 0px 100px 100px;
  color: $black;
  display: none;
}
```

And this is the JavaScript code to be executed when that button is clicked.

```
$('.link').click(function() {
  m.id = $(this).attr('data-id');
  $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
  $("div[data-id=" + m.id).slideDown();
});
$('.close').click(function() {
  $("div[data-id=" + m.id).slideUp();
  $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
})
```

Comment: what exactly do you think when said 'not work on mobile',  I tried on my mobile and on chrome web and also inspected in few mobiles views over chrome developer tools and it looks same.

Comment: Hi. You are always on the web regardless of the device ;) Could you be more specific about what is the expected result on mobile ?

Comment: I clarified in my post. I tested it on my iPhone 6 and on Safari and it doesn't work. Works on chrome and firefox and microsoft edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an open bracket that is never closed, could be the problem:

```
("div[data-id=" + m.id)
```

Try

```
("div[data-id=" + m.id + "]")
```

in all the event handlers

Comment: I tried your edit and it worked! :) It's always the simplest things.